# Ubuntu 16 systemd service on boot

Tags: service, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I have written a very simple systemd service.

The purpose of this is to create a service that will start once the booting process is done and run a python script. It should also restart the python script if the python script crashes.

This is how my systemd script looks like.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Python Script
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type = forking
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/python/script/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /path/to/my/python/script/mypythonscript.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This script has been written using this [tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/). I followed the steps there just changed names.

I now have a service that I can stat manually. If I do `sudo service myservice start` I am able to start my service. However, the service does not start when the machine boots. It needs to be started manually.

Do you know how I can fix that?

What is the correct way to have a service start after the machine boots, on a Ubuntu 16.04 OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable the service?

```
systemctl enable myservice
```

should suffice.

You can check it running systemctl status myservice, it should tell you right there if the service is enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, I did that. And after reading that multi-user.target, or targets in general are run levels, I modified the script slightly. I now how `After=multi-user.target reboot.target` and removed the `[Install]` section. After running `systemctl enable myservice` again, I get `Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction order is cyclic. See system logs for details.` when I try to reboot.

Comment: what's in syslog? And after modifying the unit you should disable/enable the service or reload the systemctl (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#daemon-reload)

Comment: I found the problem. It's not that it wasn't starting on boot. It was trying to start but it was failing more than 5 times in 10 seconds, which is the default. I changed the `StartLimitIntervalSec` and `StartLimitBurst` settings and now it starts as expected. However, I still have the `Transaction order is cyclic` problem that I'm trying to fix now.